# Correct capitalization in figure caption

Tags: capitalization, lists

I'm writing my thesis and it has many figures in it.

I was wondering when I should use upper case and when do I need to use lower case in the caption.

For example:

> Figure 23: Lateral moment vs Time

or

> Figure 23: Lateral Moment vs Time

or

> Figure 23: Lateral moment vs time.

If there are any guidelines that would really help.

Thank you.

Comment: It's something of a style issue -- whether the caption should be treated as a "headline" or not.

Answer (score 1):

This might be covered in the style guide you are following; that is, the style guide of which your chosen system of referencing is a part.

For example, in [The Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/), captions should be capitalized in "sentence style", meaning "only the first word in a title, the first word in a subtitle, and any proper names are capitalized". See section 3 in the manual.

> Figure 23: Lateral moment vs time.